# How to select distinct property values of a list of object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the below list of object:

```js
var data = [
    {
        "AcctId": 100,
        "Value": true
    },
    {
        "AcctId": 200,
        "Value": false
    }
]
```

I want to select distinct AcctId like this:

```
Output: [100, 200]
```

I've tried to use the angular filter method:

```js
var newData = data.filter(r => r.AcctId);
```

But, it's returning the same list as input. can anyone please guide me on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `data.map(v => v.AcctId)`

Comment: `data.filter(r => r.AcctId)` will just keep anything that has an ID value and that value is non-zero.

Answer (score 7):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwrify?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
this.result = Array.from(new Set(this.data.map(x => x.acctId)));
```

or,

```
 constructor() {
    this.result = this.GetDistinctValues(this.data, "acctId").map(x => x.acctId);
  }

  GetDistinctValues(Source: Array<any>, FilterKey: string = null): Array<any> {
    let DistinctArray = [];
    try {
      Source.forEach(e => {
        if (FilterKey !== null && FilterKey !== undefined && FilterKey !== "") {
          if (
            DistinctArray.filter(DE => DE[FilterKey] === e[FilterKey]).length <=
            0
          )
            DistinctArray.push(e);
        } else {
          if (DistinctArray.indexOf(e) === -1) DistinctArray.push(e);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      DistinctArray = [];
    }
    return DistinctArray;
  }
```

[Demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfice6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I used `this.result = Array.from(new Set(this.data.map(x => x.acctId).sort()));` to get the sorted result

Answer (score 0):

Or the lodash way:

```
lodash.uniq(this.data.map(x => x.acctId));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used rxjs library to

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { distinct } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Person {
age: number,
name: string
}

of<Person>(
    { age: 4, name: 'Foo'},
    { age: 7, name: 'Bar'},
    { age: 5, name: 'Foo'},
).pipe(
    distinct((p: Person) => p.name),
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```